# How to schedule reports in HP Project and Portfolio Management (PPM) Center 9.12?

Tags: pm-software

I have several reports, some are running every day, but other are not.

Where can I see and change settings for the scheduled running of reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open this web application.
2. Menu: Open -> Reports -> View Reports
3. Select Report Type and click “Search” button.
4. You see list of reports. To sort them by date to see last reports, click on Run Date header.
5. Click on Submission Details.
6. If you want to reschedule this report, click “Copy”
7. Enter details and click “Submit”.